# Copiar todo lo instalado en visual studio code a otra computadora

Tags: vscode

Les hago una pregunta, hace bastante vengo usando vsc en una computadora, le instale muchas dependencias y extenciones. Ahora cambie de pc y me gustaria tener lo mismo que tenia en la anterior. Alguien sabe como puedo ver que cosas instale o como copiar todo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: En la esquina inferior izquierda (justo arriba del logo de config) esta la seccion "Cuentas" donde podes tener respaldo en la nube. Solo tenes que tener una cuenta de Microsoft o Github para poder guardar las extensiones, configuracion, metodos abreviados del teclado, etc. Es como una cuenta de google que tiene todos los datos de tu cuenta. Al entrar en "cuentas" podes elegir la opcion "sicronizacion de configuracion" para que cualquier cambio que hagas en VSCode se guarde en la nube y puedas usarlo en otros dispositivos.

Comment: en cuanto a los proyectos los guardas con Drive o similares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución desde la página oficial de vscode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Comment: Genial gracias!! Voy a probar

Comment: De nada, funcionó?